# iTerm2 shares the same instance across all macOS workspaces

Tags: macos, terminal, console, terminal.app, iterm2

Suddenly after a computer restart, my iTerm behaves differently, as the same iTerm2 instance is shard across all macOS workspaces. 
If I open a new tab or open a new windows of iTerm2, these will appear by default on all the macOS workspaces.

I tried deleting iTerm2 and installing it again multiple times, it gave the same behaviour. 
I tried changing settings, still the same behaviour. 
I think that either I missed the right setting for this or it's a iTerm2 issue.

Similar question to this one, by that posted solution didn't solve my case: 
[iTerm2 shows up on every Space. How to keep it from doing so?](https://superuser.com/questions/657842/iterm2-shows-up-on-every-space-how-to-keep-it-from-doing-so)

Comment: So you've tried right clicking in the Dock & changing the Options>Assign To...? not just looking at it, changing it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I tried the _None_ and _This Desktop_ options. Doesn't seem to have the desired effect.
 
_This Desktop_: the instances are set only to that workspace, it doesn't appear on the other ones, but when I create a new window and I try to drag it to another workspaces, it doesn't let me to. 
_None_: the new instances are shared, they refer to the same one, across all workspaces. 

So it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your profile for all spaces:
Under preference -> profile -> window -> space : set to all spaces.

then restart iterm2